# Android FileInputStream and Socket

Tags: android, sockets

I have set server and run following codes. The server runs well but the android program stops while running. The android program is to input a certificate file and send it to server by socket. I don't know what's wrong with my codes. Thanks!

```
private Socket client;
private Button button;
private ObjectOutputStream out = null;

AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new Thread (new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client = new Socket("192.168.1.186", 4444);
                        out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = assetManager.openFd("client.crt");
                        FileInputStream in = afd.createInputStream();

                        CertificateFactory of = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                        java.security.cert.Certificate ceof = of.generateCertificate(in);

                        X509Certificate clientcert = (X509Certificate) ceof;
                        out.writeObject(clientcert);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you considered closing the streams?

Comment: Look in the log of course.  If nothing is there, add proactive logging messages.

Comment: Still doesn't work after adding closing steams